# Swift 4.2: How to embed UIPageControl in ViewController (without Storyboard)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Does anyone have an example of how to embed a `PageController` within a `ViewController` without using a `xib` or storyboard?

Is using a `UIPageControl` the right approach to build the following?

[image]

Comment: Please check this it may help  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-ios-pageviewcontroller-without-storyboards-paul-tangen

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p317pageControllerChild/ch19p626pageController/RootViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

The standard technique is along these lines:

```
    let pvc = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
    self.addChild(pvc)
    self.view.addSubview(pvc.view)
    pvc.view.frame = // whatever
    pvc.didMove(toParent: self)
    pvc.setViewControllers( //...
    pvc.dataSource = // ...
```